# Reg Expression - recording right group (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture part of an email with a regular expression. The subject line is in this format

Word Word: Word Word:WORDIWANT word word wordword

Now I can get up the 2nd colon using

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*:[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*:)
```

eg - Word Word: Word Word:

I can then get the word I want by adding (\w*) to the end so I end up with

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*:[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*:)(\w*)
```

eg - Word Word: Word Word:WORDIWANT

Now what I need is for the expression to ignore those first part, what I need is for it to record that second part only.

edit: Thanks for replies so far, unfortunately the program I'm using currently is Javascript based but won't allow anything other than regular expressions or TOKEN style results, no detailed coding.

So ideally I'm looking for just a REGEX_MATCH option

Closest I've been able to get is (?:(^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*:[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*:))|(\w*)

This will highlight the part WORDIWANT but still not sure how to make sure its only seeing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Word Word: Word Word:WORDIWANT word wordword".match(/^(?:[^:]*:){2}(\w+)/)[1];
```

In another language you could have used `positive look behind` (by replacing `?:` with `?<=`) but javascript doesn't support it.

So if you want to use this expression in a `replace` function - you need to `prepend` your first match to the replaced text (which is a workaround for a lack of look behind in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

try this (unable to test locally):

```
var myString = "Word Word: Word Word:WORDIWANT word word wordword";
var myRegexp = /(^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*:[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]:)(\w)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[2]);  // this should be WORDIWANT
```